# Problem with permissions to edit message templates

Tags: permissions, message-templates

I have recently upgraded from CiviCRM 5.24 to 5.27.2 (on Drupal 7.72), and a user reports a new problem with editing message templates, specifically the User Message Templates.  She can open the template, select edit, make the changes, but when she tries to save it gets an Authorisation Failure message.

She has the permissions Edit Message Templates, and Edit User-Driven Message Templates, which worked OK before.

Is there some change I need to make to the configuration, or is this a regression bug?

Thanks, Tony

The Error message is:

"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Authorization failed"

on a white screen.
The template text is the following, but get the same error with a single line of text without any formatting at all.:

```
{capture assign=doctype}{activity.scheduled_reminder}{/capture}
{capture assign=renewal}Renewal Reminder{/capture}
{capture assign=lapsed}Membership Lapsed{/capture}

{if $doctype == $renewal} LALG Renewal Reminder{/if}

{if $doctype == $lapsed} LALG Membership Lapsed{/if}



     {contact.first_name} {contact.last_name}
     {contact.street_address}
     {contact.supplemental_address_1}
     {contact.city}   {contact.postal_code}



{contact.email_greeting}

{if $doctype == $renewal}

Your membership will expire on  {latestcurrentmembership.end_date}

Membership Type:  {latestcurrentmembership.type}

You can find all the details as to how to renew your membership  by visiting  the LALG Website

Membership can be renewed online or by downloading a form from the website and taking this with your payment to David's bookshop.



Yours sincerely,

Elaine Fox

Chair

{/if}

{if $doctype == $lapsed}

Your LALG membership has recently expired, and you will no longer receive the monthly newsletter or other membership benefits.

Membership can be renewed online or by downloading a form from the website and taking this with your payment to David's bookshop.  You can find all the details as to how to renew your membership  by visiting  the LALG Website.

Membership Type:  {latestcurrentmembership.type}

Expiry Date:            {latestcurrentmembership.end_date}



Yours sincerely,

Elaine Fox

Chair

{/if}
```

Comment: Can you provide little more description about the error? Do you get access denied when saving the message template? Can you save the message template using user id 1 or full admin civi access?

Comment: I'm seeing the same on CiviCRM 5.27.2 and Joomla 3.9.20; is this a bug? The user has "Allowed" permissions for Edit Message Templates, and Edit User-Driven Message Templates (same as the OP reported), can open and edit the template, but when they click "Save" or "Save and Done", they're taken to an error screen with "Authorization failed" among other generic verbiage ("We are unable to provide this at this moment..."). I see the same in the error log. Looks like a bug, no?

Comment: To confirm - this is still present in CiviCRM 5.28.2.
Error occurs when trying to save a new, or edited, template with a single line of plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I've [identified the source of the problem](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/-/issues/78) and suggested a hack to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also reported as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2008, which has been "Closed ... as https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18437 is now merged."